# Setting up Salesforce to receive Leads from third party via Webservice

Tags: rest-api, inboundservices

I am setting up my organization's Salesforce instance to accept `Leads` from a third party system via web-service. Following  are the steps I took till now

- Created an Integration user in Salesforce.
- Added third party's domain in Remote Site Setting.
- Under **Setup -> Build -> Create -> Apps** I added a new Connected Apps and generated `Client Key` and `Client Secret`.

They are asking for endpoint URL. I gave them following URL

https://test.salesforce.com

They are still not able to make an authentication connection to Salesforce. Am I missing some other setup step? Is this the correct URL to use as the endpoint URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Production endpoint is https://login.salesforce.com and for sandbox endpoint is https://test.salesforce.com/. If you are using OAuth for authentication then you have to send a request for authorization at https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize and then after authorization you need to send token request at  https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token for production. Same will be the case for test environment except the endpoint will change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anmrk... However I am still getting the error saying "Salesfroce Login Exception:  Authentication Failure - Invalid Password". I am manually able but with the request it gives the invalid password.  error

Comment: which OAuth flow you are using?

Comment: @anmrk.. I was able to resolve the issue, thr was a security token issue. Thanks for your help!!